# why method Base64.encodeBase64String(byte) is not available

Tags: eclipse, apache-commons-codec

Hello I have included in my project build path apache commond codec 1.7 .jar from the official web page  but the method   `Base64.encodeBase64String(byte` is  not available when I write my code.
I have tested with older versions of the jar (1.5, 1.6) but nothing works.

Thank you!

Comment: After struggling I found out that axi2 has in its lib directory a lower version of this jar common codec 1.3 so that's why encodeBase64String was unavailable. After changing it everything works. I hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Since I found this while searching for a similar problem I figured I would post it here so people can find it.  The maven repository has a version of this library "20041127.091804" I assume this is a glitch where the date somehow got dumped into the version number but it shows up as the latest version and does not include this function.  You can click on the versions button next to it and see that it is from 2005 and the latest version (as of when I write this) is 1.8.  Hope this helps.