# Can not resolve method 'Base64.encodeBase64String(byte[])'

Tags: java, android, encryption, encoding, aes

I am working on AES encryption and decryption in Android and for that, I have used [this](http://aesencryption.net/) site and code.

After implementing the java file I am getting the error `Can not resolve method Base64.encodeBase64String(byte[])`.

I have found possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16169008/why-method-base64-encodebase64stringbyte-is-not-available) but It doesn't work for me.

My target is to get, **Encrypted Result: +xsGMAefodr7u/bfTIdqoQ==** for **String: hello world**, **Key: password** and **Bit: 128**.

Thanks.

Comment: you have to check which package of `Base64` you are importing. the example code in your link uses `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` , but the [android.util.Base64](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) does not have `encodeBase64String` method

Comment: If you want to use apache commons codec, you have to write `compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'` in your gradle setting. [site](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccommons-codec%7Ccommons-codec%7C1.10%7Cjar)

Comment: "I have found possible duplicate but It doesn't work for me." That's not a very good error description, don't you agree? Note that that's a horrible example of performing AES encryption, maybe you should take a few lessons. Then you can mail the guy that wrote the code fragment his mistakes afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following:

```
import android.util.Base64;
String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(byte[], Base64.NO_WRAP);
```